# La funcion onclick de una card afecta a las otras cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs

soy novato en react y tengo un problema. Resulta ser que hago un map de un array para mostrar unas simples cards(con imagen y descripcion), a este le pongo un button con una funcion toggle que muestre un párrafo. Mi problema es que al apretar un boton se abre y cierran todas las cards. Se que tiene que ver con que debería pasar una especie de key para que sepa distinguir cada card pero no se como hacerlo y donde. me podrán ayudar? desde ya mil gracias.

código :

```
export default function App() {
  const [activado, setActivado] = useState(false)

  function handleClick() {
    setActivado(!activado)
  }

  return (
    <main>
      {cardsContent.map((item) => {
        return (
          <figure key={item.id}>
            <img src={item.img} alt={item.title} />
            <figcaption>{item.title}
              <button onClick={handleClick}>
                +
              </button>
            </figcaption>
            {
              activado &&
              <p>informacion adicional</p>
            }
          </figure>
        )
      }

      )}
    </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: Wena pregunta...

Comment: creo que el estado ``activado`` en lugar de ser un ``bool`` podria ser una variable inicializada en ``null``. Luego tendrias que agregar un index al map para tener el indice donde se está iterando: ``cardsContent.map((item, index) =>``.  El boton deberia hacer ``<button onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>`` y tendrias que reformular tu funcion handleClick para que reciba un index y lo setee en el estado. Con eso deberia alcanzar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el estado no alcanza con saber si activado es true o false, deberias saber tambien cual es la card que queres mostrar. Por eso lo cambio de `false` a `null`.

Luego reformulo la funcion `handleClick`, si le paso un `id` lo voy a setear en `activado`, si no le paso nada, hago `activado = null`, (esto te va a servir para cuando quieras cerrar la card y que se deje de mostrar la info)

Luego te habia comentado lo del indice, pero lo mejor seria usar el `id` asi que lo unico que haces es pasarle a la funcion onClick del boton `handleClick(id)`.

Ahora cada vez que hagas click en una card deberia cambiar el texto del parrafo, y podrias agregar un boton para que cierre este parrafo:

> <button onClick={() => hanldeClick()}>Cerrar < /button>

```
export default function App() {
  const [activado, setActivado] = useState(null)

  const handleClick = id => id ? setActivado(id) : setActivado(null)


  return (
    <main>
      {cardsContent.map((item) => {
        return (
          <figure key={item.id}>
            <img src={item.img} alt={item.title} />
            <figcaption>{item.title}
              <button onClick={() => handleClick(item.id)}>
                +
              </button>
            </figcaption>
            {
              (activado && activado === item.id) &&
              <p>informacion adicional de la card {activado}</p>
            }
          </figure>
        )
      }

      )}
    </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: Agustin lo probé y me sirvió.  Utilice para los botones un ternario,  con + para abrir y - para cerrar. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo . Un saludo!